# Animate Subview to Middle

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiviewanimation, subview

I have a subview that I've created in a xib file. It is in the middle of the screen where I ultimately want it to be. I am trying to animate it so that it moves to the middle from the bottom when a button is pressed to show the view and I want it animate to the bottom when the view is closed. The way it is now, it starts in the middle where it is in the xib and animates up from there. How can I get it to start at the bottom and move to the middle?

In viewDidLoad: I set the starting frame.

```
CGRect newFrame = self.findFriendView.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y += 1000;
    self.findFriendView.frame = newFrame;
    self.findFriendView.hidden = YES;
```

Here is the method for the button press to show the subview.

```
- (void)addFriend {
    self.followersTableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    self.findFriendView.hidden = NO;

    CGRect newFrame = self.findFriendView.frame;
    newFrame.origin.y -= 1000;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0
                     animations:^{self.findFriendView.frame = newFrame;}
                     completion:nil];
}
```

[image]

Comment: How can you set frame , when you are using auto layout in your project? for doing the animation you have to update the constraint.

Comment: if you are on auto-layout, you need to modify the _constraint_ instead of the _frame_...

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a very strange way of doing this. Why not just create a second view controller in your storyboard and present it as a modal form sheet?

Then you could just do the following:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle:nil];
YourNewViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourNewViewControllerID"];

viewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
viewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and if you need to send any data to the new controller, you can just put this in the .h of the new controller:

```
@property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) NSDictionary * IncomingData;
```

and then create an NSDictionary containing whatever data you want in your master view and send it with the following line (put it just before the presentviewcontroller):

```
viewController.IncomingData = tempDict;
```

EDIT:

OP is not using storyboards so rather than:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"iPad" bundle:nil];
YourNewViewController *viewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"YourNewViewControllerID"];
```

You need to do:

```
YourNewViewController =  [[YourNewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"YourNewViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Comment: I'm not using storyboards

Comment: After I dismiss the new view controller, how can I reload the table view in the view controller I am presenting the new controller from?

Comment: Send an NSNotification from the newly presented view to the main view and when the NSNotification is received just do a [tableView reloadData];